# using multiple css3 animations for an element

Tags: css, animation

I'm really confused with this one. I want my element (a moon) to drop down from top of the page where it is invisible and then immediately rotate once. But, unfortunately I couldn't make it. It drops down, then it waits a second or two, rotates and then it disapears. But I want it to stay in the page.
This my code:

```
.moon {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-700px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-700px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-700px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-700px);
    transform: translateY(-700px);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation: moon 4s cubic-bezier(.49,.05,.32,1.04) 1s 1 ;
    animation: moon 4s cubic-bezier(.49,.05,.32,1.04) 1s 1 ;

}

@-webkit-keyframes moon {
    45%   {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }

    75%   {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

    100%   {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }

}

<svg version="1.1" id="Mitena" class="mitena-logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="540px" height="540px" viewBox="0 0 540 540" enable-background="new 0 0 540 540" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Moon" class="moon">
     <path fill="blue" d="M260.858,9.204c-19.984,0-40.052,3.614-59.671,10.145c12.791-2.281,26.229-3.795,40.355-4.417
      c142.722-6.282,255.68,105.785,255.321,242.176c-0.455,165.917-129.458,241.071-240.945,240.161
      C113.667,496.123,14.171,397.187,7.45,256.812c-0.175-3.653-0.249-7.333-0.24-11.03c-1.228,9.561-1.656,18.999-1.196,28.216
      c7.606,152.364,118.345,257.64,275,257.64c140.437,0,254.818-95.765,254.818-254.772C535.832,128.59,424.337,9.204,260.858,9.204z
     "/>
</g>
</svg>
```

this is a running example:

http://jsfiddle.net/12jkrxsg/

Comment: If you want to keep the state of the end of the animation, add *forwards* to the animation property

Answer (score 1):

Like @vals said you should use the `forwards` for `animation-fill-mode` according to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp).

Also you can try creating the element in it's end position first. So let's say that you want the element to animate and end up in the center of the page. You should build the element and style it to be in the center of the page. Then you can add an animation to it, and once the animation finishes, it will reset the element to it's original state, which will be the center of the page. Was that clear?